# I am a Windows user and still find the same error while running the code

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried multiple possible ways but still find the same error.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder\Part 1 - Data Preprocessing\Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
print(x)
print(y)
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-6-4980dfab92dc> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder\Part 1 - Data Preprocessing\Data.csv')
      2 X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
      3 y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

4 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)    1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols    1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)    1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols    1893 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File D:\Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder\Part 1 - Data Preprocessing\Data.csv does not exist: 'D:\\Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder\\Part 1 - Data Preprocessing\\Data.csv'
```

Comment: based on your error message I believe you have entered your path wrongly or FIle name wrongly. check it.
Also try to add  \\  while reading  csv i.e  `pd.read_csv('D:\\Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder\\Part 1 - Data Preprocessing\\Data.csv')'

Comment: @ccl: thanks for wanting to improve posts here. In general, if you see a stack trace, they are better with block formatting rather than quote formatting. Things are generally rendered in consoles in a columnar fashion, and they are more readable if they are rendered in a monospace font. See my edit.